# Converting a string to a "URL Safe" string for Twilio

Tags: c#, url, twilio

This isn't Twilio specific, but the issue does cause the Twilio API call to fail..

I'm wanting to generate an XML file via Twilio's lab:

```
http://twimlets.com/echo?Twiml=%3CResponse%3E%3CSay%3EHi+there.%3C%2FSay%3E%3C%2FResponse%3E
```

The above URL works great as a parameter in the API and obviously works if you use your browser to view the output.

I can also view the following in the browser, and it works fine, but this version of the URL fails as a parameter to the Twilio API

```
http://twimlets.com/echo?Twiml=Response><Say>Hi+there.</Say></Response>
```

For readability and debugging I would *much* prefer to have the second URL.  Is there a library or other way in C# to convert the second, pretty URL to the first, replacing %3C with the '<' character and so on?  I could then just do the replacement right before I send it off to the API since my app pushes around and stores the pretty version everywhere else. I can of course write one myself to do the conversion, but it seems like this would be a common problem.  Thanks!

Comment: Yep.  Thanks!  I'd never had to do this before and wasn't sure where this was.  I Googled for it but answers seemed to all be around making them "safe for the web" or "SEO friendly", which was totally not what I needed.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Is this perhaps what you are looking for?

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string encoded = "http://twimlets.com/echo?Twiml=%3CResponse%3E%3CSay%3EHi+there.%3C%2FSay%3E%3C%2FResponse%3E";
   string decoded = Uri.UnescapeDataString(encoded);
}
```

Output - Unescaped string:

```
http://twimlets.com/echo?Twiml=<Response><Say>Hi+there.</Say></Response>
```

And back to normal:

```
string encoded = Uri.EscapeDataString(decoded);
```

Output - escaped string:

```
http://twimlets.com/echo?Twiml=%3CResponse%3E%3CSay%3EHi+there.%3C%2FSay%3E%3C%2FResponse%3E
```